# Python Simple HTTP Server Batch File Error

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I'm currently playing around with home networking and getting into servers and I found a python command that will make the directories of you python folder avaliable over your LAN. To execute it in windows, I've just been entering the following into Command Prompt:

```
cd..
cd..
cd Python33
python -m http.server 8000
```

This creates the server that can be accessed via x.x.x.x:8000. Instead of manually entering these commands every time, however, I tried to make a batch script that would do this automatically. Below is the script for the batch file. The problem I'm having, is When I run the batch file, command prompt is saying 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I was wondering if someone could tell my why this is happening and offer a solution or reason as to why this couldn't work. Thanks.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd..
cd..
cd Python33
python -m http.server 8000
pause
```

EDIT: 
Below is the code that works, this will also set the directory to the C drive.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\
C:\Python33\python -m http.server 8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because the batch file is located in a directory that is not 2- level deep (`C:\path\to\batch.bat`)

Specifying the path of the python executable will solve your problem.

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\python33\python -m http.server 8000
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd..
cd..
cd Python33
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
pause
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, `SimpleHTTPServer` is renmaed to `http.server`.

Comment: Although the `SimpleHTTPServer` would work with native consoles on UNIX based systems.